# Apache Commons Discovery Javadoc References ScopedProperties Class. Where Is That Class?

Tags: java, apache-commons

I hate to have to ask a question like this, but after a considerable amount of time searching Google, the latest java runtime API, and the commons-discovery API I feel I've reached a dead end. My question simply is, does anyone know what the ScopedProperties class is that commons-discovery refers to, or where the class definition exists? In the javadoc for many of their classes, they make refernces like the following:

> The value of the (scoped) system property whose name is the same as the SPI's fully qualified class name (as given by SPI.class.getName()). The ScopedProperties class provides a way to bind properties by classloader, in a secure hierarchy similar in concept to the way classloader find class and resource files. See ScopedProperties for more details.

See [DiscoverClass](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-discovery/apidocs/index.html)

However, like I've mentioned above, I done some searching but cannot find this class anywhere within their API nor the standard Java 7 runtime API. I wish I didn't have to deal with commons-discovery, but unfortunately there are constraints which require me to do so. If anyone could assist with discovering this class (sorry, couldn't help myself), I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have the fully qualified name?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The information above is all the commons-discovery javadoc gives. I was hoping that through some googling and referring to JRE 7 API I would uncover a JRE class with that name, but nothing.